# When does an SVG element in a directive get updated?

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

Consider a directive of type "svg" that uses a template to render an SVG element within an SVG in the existing DOM:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('component', ['$timeout', function($timeout){

    return {
        type: 'svg',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'template.svg',

        link: function (scope, element) {

            var dir = angular.element(document.createElement('my-directive'));
            dir.attr('id', 'test');
            $compile( dir )( scope );
            element.append(dir);

            $timeout(function(){
                var el = document.getElementById('test');

                var bb  = el.getBoundingClientRect();

                scope.rectWidth = bb.width;
                scope.rectHeight = bb.height;
            }, 0);

        }
    };

}]);
```

Here is the template:

```
<rect width="{{rectWidth}}" height="{{rectHeight}}"></rect>
```

The intention is that the dimensions are updated after the DOM has been rendered. The dimensions aren't updated about half of the time - especially with more than a few of this directive element on the page. I have read that `$timeout` will ensure that the HTML DOM is rendered before the function runs. How can I ensure that the SVG has updated before I measure the appended element's size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listening for [`DOMSubtreeModified`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) on the element solves this for the time being, but that event is deprecated. The proper way to solve this is to use the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface.